# How to secure API end points in custom activities?

Tags: journeybuilder, security, fuel-sdk, activities, custom-activity

I have a custom activity created for the journey builder. From a security point of view, how can I protect my *REST* endpoints? I know we can get the fuel token in the *getToken* method from *postmonger*.
What would be the best implementation to use this token and secure my endpoints?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?